# How to get the reboot times

Tags: raspbian

The `who -b` command desn't show me  the last reboot times on my Raspberry 3

```
    :~ $ uname -a
Linux xxxxx 4.9.35-v7+ #1014 SMP Fri Jun 30 14:47:43 BST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
:~ $ who -b 
    system boot  1970-01-01 01:00
```

I configured the ntp daemon as the date is uptodate.

How to configure the system for getting this king of information.

Regards,

Comment: "who -b" should work. 
"last reboot" is also borked
This is a bug

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer.  Use:  `uptime -s`

You can use the `uptime` command to find out how long it has been since the Pi (or any Unix/Linux OS) has booted.  The `-s` flag tells uptime to calculate the boot time.

The Pi doesn't have a real-time clock (though there are RTC chips that you can add).  This means it does not know the date/time as it boots.  If it has access to a network, it'll reach out to a time server to set these.  But if it doesn't have a network, it will rely on a fake hardware clock (basically a file where it periodically writes the time.  It isn't accurate but at least it fixes problems where log files have "newer" entries with older date/time stamps than "older" entries.

See:  [How is time kept on the Raspberry Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1601/how-is-time-kept-on-the-raspberry-pi)